# Host Interceptor gives localhost as hostname in aws

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, apache-2.2

This is a repost of the question I asked in stackoverflow

I'm trying to write my apache logs from my ec2 instances. I want the logs separated by hostname.

I'm using host interceptor to get the hostname. My configuration is below.

`agent1.sources.spooldir-source1.interceptors = i1 hostname agent1.sources.spooldir-source1.interceptors.i1.type = timestamp agent1.sources.spooldir-source1.interceptors.hostname.type = host agent1.sources.spooldir-source1.interceptors.hostname.useIP = false agent1.sources.spooldir-source1.interceptors.hostname.preserveExisting = true`

But, flume writes the logs to directory called localhost. This is not suitable for me.

I have not changed the default hostname of aws instance.

ie, If the default hostname is like the below one.

`bitnami@ip-10-242-197-46:~$ hostname

ip-10-242-197-46`

I want the logs to be written in a directory called ip-10-242-197-46 instead of localhost

Answer (score 0):

What I suspect is that you are trying to access the application from localhost. For ex:

If you try like this:

```
# telnet localhost 80
```

then it will put localhost in the logs.

But if you try the same application like this:

```
# telnet 10-242-197-46 80
```

then it will put the hostname which you are expeting in the logs.

So, I believe you should try to access the application from eth0 device, instead of localhost.